# How do I find out where the page loading fails in my jsf page?

Tags: jsf-2.2, wildfly-10

I'm trying to migrate an application from wildfly 9.0.1 to wildfly 10.1 and when I try to access the page I get [this error](https://pastebin.com/muNYLKjQ).

The only component I could think of in my page related to it is a `selectManyCheckbox` maybe but I can't find anything that tries to render an "enable" string.

Comment: Stacktraces inline in the question please

Comment: @Kukeltje that was my initial intention but I couldn't submit the question here because the validation error said there is too much code and not enough details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it was a property set in my web.xml to blame:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
```